# Narrowing a generic typescript function based on a closures type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a higher-order function (a react hook, but that doesn't really matter re the function signature) which takes an enum, and returns a function that checks if the value of the enum matches the provided one

When calling the function it doesn't properly narrow the types when used in a conditional, so that in the below example, status remains as `SomeStatusEnum`

```
// status: SomeStatusEnum
const didTransitionTo = useDidTransition(status);

if (didTransitionTo(SomeStatusEnum.SUCCESS)) {
  // status is not narrowed to .SUCCESS here
}
```

The original implementation was this

```
/**
 * A hook that given a value T, returns a predicate
 * function which will return true when _entering_
 * a matching state
 */

export function useDidTransition<S>(status: S) {
  const prevStatus = usePreviousValue(status);

  /**
   * Did the status transition into `to`, from
   * any other value at all
   */
  function didTransitionTo(to: S): boolean {
    return to !== prevStatus && to === status;
  }

  return didTransitionTo;
}
```

The below attempt at fixing it with a type guard gives the error `Cannot find parameter 'status'`, as `status` is in the outer scope, not a param of didTransitionTo

```
export function useDidTransition<S>(status: S) {
  const prevStatus = usePreviousValue(status);

  function didTransitionTo<To extends S>(to: To): status is To {
    return to !== prevStatus && to === status;
  }

  return didTransitionTo;
}
```

Edit: [TS playground with attempted fix here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDCmA8AcHsCcBcAEAzArgOwMbwJbXYqgM6gAiOAJgCqwCG6ROu+APAILoCeAyvLfMQB8ACiJ8BRAFyIOPccQCUiAN7BEiTPjGJIsUADde-YogC8hEgAU9+vMQBqtADapQo+UQUBuEOrRZmAgpKGnpGQKpoFlJQRj0KIwlECHhQdAoiGS5EoWF4aGkYuNAEjwVpMWNMnEyinHiczNV1dT0BWAJ8xABCU3NdA0bEADJhxC6+80qJH3UAX19ENtQOxGDqOgYmPHRInwWwdFQAW0QAWTkqlTVEABkAeTZSAEkAOQBxABob7gBVAGF-gBRbjcYAHAD0EMQr2gSHQtFgsGgAHcSp8NNBUE4KIgAEacRD0QkXRrAJygJCYFZ6dDwIbmUkeAB0Dyeb3eRMyTKqIE0DCQ61CWwi0DMFjIIU24R2wmpSLS9LKIBwyEQwiF0u2+Eiwh5EmZf0BIO4CiUzQ0NMVZPUUMQz0QKPoVKtdKGXTxoEQCKRqJK4zF+uIhoBwNBGPQcPOlwk4JAwDtADFaABrf2MLBetEAcj03qjOAIelo2GA-mwOwl1gMdiIjhcoBYVBE4GkVHKiCoKiWlJWBHltKVV1omS7cyAA)

I'd rather just drop use of the function than make `didTransitionTo` take `status` as well

Comment: Why is the hook generic over S? Please create a minimum reproducible example including how you're calling this and the enum you're calling it with. Preferably with a link to a TS playground or stackblitz or whatever that shows the issue. Also, why would you expect the *type* to be narrowed to a specific enum variant here?

Comment: @JaredSmith Added a link to the body (too long to paste in a comment). I'd expect the type of the enum to be narrowd here because it does so when not wrapped in the generic. E.g. this correctly narrows it to PENDING in the scope of the conditional
```
  if (
      previousStatus !== MyStatus.PENDING &&
      status === MyStatus.PENDING
    ) {}
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't curry type guard functions, see [ms/TS#16410](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16410). There's no way to do this.  You would need to make `didTransitionTo` take `status` as well, which you don't want to do, so the answer here is "this is impossible, sorry". Does that fully address the question? If so I can write up an answer (although it's mostly just the above link and a sad face). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Nope that answers it @jcalz - I'd searched around for closures/higher order functions but forgot to look up currying so I missed that issue. I'm not sure what SO etiquette is here, if you answer it with "this is impossible, sorry" I can accept it, or close the issue

Comment: I'll post an answer, might as well keep the question undeleted for the next people who run into this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) functions that return a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) so that the predicate acts on a parameter of the outer scope.  That is, you can't refactor `(x: X, y: Y) => x is Z` to `(x: X) => (y: Y) => x is Z`.  Type predicates can only refer directly to one of the parameters directly in the signature (or `this`).  See [microsoft/TypeScript#16410](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16410) for more information.

You could *uncurry* your `<S>(status: S) => <T extends S>(to: T) => status is T` function to the form `<S, T extends S>(status: S, to: T) => status is T`.  Or, as you said, you could drop the function entirely instead.